# What exactly is a skew field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading a text wich says: "Let $k\subset K$ be a skew field extension." Now I know what a *field extension* is, but I'm not quite sure what to think of a *skew field extension*. Also, how would you construct such an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A,B$ are two arbitrary algebraic objects, then an extension $A \to B$ is by definition a monomorphism $A \to B$. This includes the notions of ring extension, field extension, skew field extension, etc. Notice that in the category of skew fields every morphism is a monomorphism. Hence, an extension of skew fields is just a homomorphism of skew fields. Often this homomorphism is assumed to be an inclusion of sets (which is not necessary and in fact, in my opinion, a little bit misleading, because basic examples such as $k \to k[x]/(f)$ are not inclusions).

Comment: PS: The question "Also, how would you construct such an object?" is too general to be answered.

Comment: Not to spoil Martin's soup, but I have never heard of "module extension" being used for a monomorphism of modules -- instead it often means an isomorphism class of short exact sequences. I'd say the meaning of the word depends on the category, alas.

Comment: That's right, thank you for that addition.

Comment: On the other hand, the notions are compatible. An extension of modules $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ is completely determined by the monomorphism $A \to B$. In fact, $B \to C$ is just a cokernel of $A \to B$.

Comment: Ah, that's a nice viewpoint!